# rails gem:install not installing gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey all!  I am using Aptana studio v2.0.5.1278522500 for RoR development and am running into trouble with gem installation.  I'm a noob here so hopefully I'm just doing something stupid.

I've added this line to the environment.rb file:

```
config.gem 'mislav-will_paginate', :verion => '>=2.3.2',
                                   :lib => 'will_paginate',
                                   :source => 'http://gems.github.com'
```

Then I run rake gems:install like so:

```
>rake gems:install
(in C:/.../My Documents/Aptana Studio Workspace/blog)
gem install mislav-will_paginate --source http://gems.github.com
Successfully installed mislav-will_paginate-2.3.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mislav-will_paginate-2.3.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for mislav-will_paginate-2.3.11...
>
```

If I run a rake gems to verify that it was installed I get:

```
>rake gems

(in C:/Users/Stevo/My Documents/Aptana Studio Workspace/blog)
 - [I] RedCloth 
 - [ ] mislav-will_paginate 

I = Installed
F = Frozen
R = Framework (loaded before rails starts)
>>
```

And I try to run my app I get:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
Missing these required gems:
  mislav-will_paginate  

You're running:
  ruby 1.9.1.378 at D:/Ruby191/bin/ruby.exe
  rubygems 1.3.7 at C:/Users/Stevo/.gem/ruby/1.9.1, D:/Ruby191/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1

Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

Any ideas what I'm messing up here?

Comment: Does it work if you run the commands as superuser with `sudo`?

Comment: Some tips: Avoid Ruby 1.9.1. Use 1.8.7 or 1.9.2. Use `bundle install` to install the gems mentioned 
in your Gemfile. If you are just now learning Rails, I suggest you start with Rails version 3.x instead
of 2.x. Also, avoid using any IDE - you will learn much more without the IDE doing its "magic".
For your current problem, see if the place you installed the gem using `rake` is the same as the folder
returned by `gem which mislav...`.

Comment: You have a typo too: `verion` should be `version` in `config.gem`

Comment: Good points all.  Unfortunately I've been so busy at work that I haven't had time to develop my rails hobby.  When I have time to get back into this I'll jump to Rails 3.x and drop the IDE.